# macOS Swift Safari-like tabs

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

I want to add the tabbing mechanism that you can see e.g. in Safari, the Console or the Finder (http://dailymactips.com/working-with-finder-tabs-on-your-mac/). I have already searched a lot, but I can not find a good guide for this.

Ideally, I want to be able to push an alert-dialog before a new tab is created by the user.

Comment: So you only want help on the Alert or on the Tab functionality too?

Comment: On both. I have no idea how i can achieve this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSWindow` has native tabs for a couple of years now.

The "Whats new in Cocoa" session from WWDC 2016 is the best place to start, since the documentation is quite thin still.

[Whats New In Cocoa (203 WWDC 2016)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/203/)

If you are using (for example) the method [addTabbedWindow::ordered:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1855947-addtabbedwindow?language=objc), you can simply show your alert before adding the tab.

Comment: do you also know how i can get the tab bar showing when i have only one tab?

Comment: Not sure; but did you try calling toggleTabBar: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1644517-toggletabbar)?

Comment: NSWindows tab feature is covered briefly in WWDC 2017, not 2016: https://developer.apple.com/videos/all-videos/?q=what%27s%20new%20in%20cocoa