# How to create web browser like tabs for WKWebView for Mac app? [Objective C]

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, tabs, wkwebview

I already have a webview in my `Mac app`. Now I need to implement tabs like Safari (for example). I searched some and didn't got any one for `Cocoa App`. Some libraries I found was too old and was not able to change it to running condition. I found a lot for `iOS apps` `Cocoa Touch`. Is there any solution for giving tabs for a webview?

**IF THIS IS A DUPLICATE QUESTION, PLEASE MENTION AT LEAST AN ALMOST EXACT ORIGINAL**

**OBJECTIVE - C PLEASE**

Comment: check out this https://github.com/MiMo42/MMTabBarView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [macOS Swift Safari-like tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830321/macos-swift-safari-like-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

For tabs, `NSWindow` provides all the functionality you need. Basically, you get tabs for free, including the ability for users to drag/drop tabs to windows and vice versa.
For grouping several windows/tabs together, there is [`webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/1536907-webview?language=objc) in the UI delegate, which tells you how to open the new window/tab and gives you an opportunity to set the webview up.